# a good regular expression determining strong ,medium and weak password

Tags: jquery, regex

how to make regular expression to indicate that a password is strong, medium or weak in jquery

Comment: Do you think that `adfjvmfizkgl` is weak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [jquery password strength](http://n0nick.net/jquery/password-strength/) plugin directly.

Answer (score 3):

- [Ajax Password Strength Meter Script](http://simplythebest.net/scripts/ajax/ajax_password_strength.html)
- [Password Strength Validation with Regular Expressions](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/)
- [Check Password Strength with JavaScript and Regular Expressions](http://www.marketingtechblog.com/programming/javascript-password-strength/)